# Easiest way to display POST data from form, with WordPress backend?

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I have a standard HTML form on a WordPress post that the visitor will fill out. It consists of mostly checkboxes. What I would like, is after the form is submitted, a page is then presented to the user showing what they checked. For example, if the visitor checked off Checkbox A, B, and E, (but not C and D) then upon submission they would see the following:

```
You submitted:
Checkbox Value A
Checkbox Value B
Checkbox Value E
```

Obviously I can do this with just PHP, but my client would like to be able to modify the form options.  Therefore I will need an easy to use backend.

Is there a plugin or user friendly way that this can be created?  Or is my best bet to start building it myself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the easiest way would be:

```
<pre>
<?php var_dump($_POST);?>
</pre>
```

but you can style it like:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$post_data){
        echo "You posted:" . $key . " = " . $post_data . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

**Note** that this might give errors if the `$post_data` type can't be displayed as a string, like an array in the POST data. This can be extended to:

```
<?php
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$post_data){
        if(is_array($post_data)){
            echo "You posted:" . $key . " = " . print_r($post_data, true) . "<br>";
        } else {
            echo "You posted:" . $key . " = " . $post_data . "<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! While this should work to output the results, I am looking for a way that would allow for the admin to edit the form in the WordPress backend, too.

Comment: This question belongs to the wordpress site then. I only answered the PHP related part. You can check [wordpress.stackexchange.com](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) if there are any related answers for your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna to show a json encoded list of the `POST` array is simple as

```
<?php echo json_encode($_POST);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something in jQuery.

```
$.post(
    "post.php",
    {checkbox : 1, checkbox2 : 0, checkbox3 : 0}, // this is the body of the post request
    function(data) {
       alert('page content: ' + data); // look up values in checkboxes and display them
    }
);
```

Im not sure what kind of data wordpress needs, it might also need some session id to be sent if you need the user to be logged in.

Comment: I hadn't actually considered jQuery for this, but perhaps that will do the trick.  Thanks for the idea!